# ssh-keygen -c comment not supported for my format

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

I'm trying to change the email display on my ssh key with this command

```
sudo ssh-keygen -c -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C "mymail@themail.com"
```

But when I do that, I got this output:

> `Comments are only supported for keys stored in the new format (-o).`

Do you know how can I change this without changing my key ? because it's an embarassing situation for me.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The text added to a key by the -C parameter [is a just a comment](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen). That means you can just open it with a text editor and change the value (and it makes no difference), [like it says in this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/a/309173).

Comment: But I found this case where people explain it doesn't change anything and after this their passwd stopped to work
https://superuser.com/questions/361764/how-can-i-change-the-comment-field-of-an-rsa-key-ssh

Comment: But did you generate you password through Putty? Since you were using ssh-keygen, I assumed that was not the case. If it is, you could always go to the original key, change the comment then generate the Putty one again (but yeah, that would make a "different" one).

Comment: No, I don't. I juste want to be sure because I don't want to my ssh key change. I will try it locally later.
thanks.